# Firebase Analytics - Activate after user consent

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-analytics

I am working on react js project . I am using Firebase analytics to track users .

Can anybody provide me some information on how to disable / enable Firebase Analytics data collection depending on user consent?

I found this documentation [firebase.google.com/docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection?platform=ios) but I am not sure if it works on **web** application.
I tried to set `Analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false)` and `FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED : false` in **firebase.json** project file but I still get the user data on google analytics dashboard when he lands on my website .

```
 "firebase": "^8.6.5",
 "react": "^17.0.2",
```

Thank you in advanced